# How to get directory permissions without backtick evaluation?

Tags: bash, file, permissions

I'm updating a Bash script in z/OS. The current script uses the result of a backtick command to test a certain condition, like so:

```
var=`command`
[test value of var]
```

The problem is that one customer has no access to the /tmp directory, and z/OS uses files in /tmp to hold intermediate data for backtick commands.

I figure I could do a test before the backtick command for /tmp accessibility, and change the script's behavior accordingly. I'm not finding a good way to do that, though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if [[ -w /tmp ]]...` will test if the current user has write access to `/tmp`.

There might be another alternative.  I don't have z/OS, but some UNIXs have a variable `TMPDIR` which can be set to a temporary directory, so for example:

```
export TMPDIR="$HOME"
```

might work.

On another note, backticks are generally considered to be deprecated.  Use `var=$(command)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

In bash you can use the `test` built-in to test file permissions.

So you can use `test -d /tmp` to check if `/tmp` is a directory or use `test -w /tmp` to test if `/tmp` is writable for you.

You can also use the `[` as a synonym for `test` like in

```
if [ -d /tmp -a -w /tmp ] ; then 
    echo "/tmp is a directory and writable"
fi
```

see `help test` in bash. It explains all the available tests.

Another thing: sometimes programs can be told which directory to use for temporary data like in `sort -T /home/user/tmp` and sometimes they repect the `TMPDIR` environment variable. Depends on the program you execute within your backticks.